# Wordpress page content and posts in the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm pretty new in world of wordpress and I'm trying to adjust HTML page into wordpress theme. 
I need **a page content** to be displayed first on a page and under that, **the posts** should be shown. But what I'm getting are just posts shown twice on the page (where page content should be). Is there any possibility to overcome this?

And additional question, how to filter posts according to their category? I've tried with `query_posts('cat=Small')`, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

The code for `index.php` looks as following:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>


<section>
  <header class="major">
    <h2>Erat lacinia</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="features">
    <?php query_posts('cat=Small'); ?>
      <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article>
         <span class="icon fa-diamond"></span>
           <div class="content">
              <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
              <p><?php the_content('Read More'); ?></p>
           </div>
        </article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This may help you

```
<section>
<div class="major">
<h2>Erat lacinia</h2>
</div>
<div class="features">
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
    );?>
<?php query_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article>
     <span class="icon fa-diamond"></span>
       <div class="content">
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <p><?php the_content('Read More'); ?></p>
       </div>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> 
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. It shows just the posts without page content :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops.

In your php page template, first execute the regular loop to get the content of the actual page, like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   //output page content here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then you define a new query for the desired posts:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    )
);
//(Add and change arguments as desired in the array above)
$loop1 = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post(); 
   //Output the post contents in a loop here    
<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

And then add the rest of the page template (footer etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
/*
 *Template name: test
 */

 get_header(); 
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $attrs = array(
          'numberposts' => 10,
          'post_type'   => 'post',
          'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'small' )
                )
            )
        );
        $my_posts = get_posts( $attrs );
        the_content();
        ?>


                  <?php if ($my_posts): ?>
                    <section>
                      <header class="major">
                        <h2>Erat lacinia</h2>
                      </header>
                      <div class="features">
                        <?php foreach ($my_posts as $key => $value): ?>
                             <article>
                                 <span class="icon fa-diamond"></span>
                                   <div class="content">
                                      <h3><?= $value->post_title; ?></h3>
                                      <p><?= $value->post_content ?></p>
                                   </div>
                                </article>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                      </div>
                      </section>
                  <?php endif ?>
        <?php
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```